# Find the current in the circuit after 20s if the initial current was 0

Tags: inductance

An inductor in an electric circuit is essentially a coil of wire in which the voltage is affected by a changing current.  By definition, the voltage caused by the changing current is given by \$V_L=L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$, where L is the inductance (in H).  If \$V_L=9.0-0.01t\$ for a 3.0-H inductor, find the current in the circuit after 20s if the initial current was 0.

I am trying to figure our where to start.  Would you integrate \$9.0-0.01t\$, multiply that by 3H, then plug in 20s for t?

Answer (score 2):

reorganize your \$V_L=L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ so that you can have a finite integral for I on the LHS and the relationship with time on the RHS, the Initial Conditions are given.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to figure our where to start.

\$v_L = 9.0 - 0.01t = L \dfrac{di_L}{dt} \$

\$\dfrac{di_L}{dt} = \dfrac{9.0 - 0.01t}{L} \$

\$di_L = (3 + \dfrac{0.01}{3}t) dt \$

\$\rightarrow i_L(t) = i_L(0) + ... \$